# GDI+ drawing text on specified coordinates on a form

Tags: c#

can someone please give me a c# example of drawing a string using GDI+ on specified coordinates?

btw i apologize for the banner advertisement above this post, i am not responsible for posting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to override the OnPaint method:

```
public class Form1
{
   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnPaint(e);
      e.Graphics.DrawString("MyString", new Font("Comic Sans MS", 12.0f), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new PointF(50.0f, 50.0f));
   }
}
```

This will draw "MyString" in red at 50,50.

Comment: Use TextRenderer.DrawText, not Graphics.DrawString